# How to change state of all togglebuttons on one kivy screen on button press?

Tags: python, kivy

I've been teaching myself Kivy (and OOP) by working on an app to collect data in real time. It involves a couple screens, but I'm having trouble with my fourth screen, which dynamically populates a GridLayout based on the selections on the third screen. The selections will be listed in a row with a few options, one being a set of 3 toggle buttons, and the rest are checkmarks.

I've created a 'reset' button on the bottom if you want to clear everything you've put in, and it clears my checkboxes just fine, but for some reason it only resets the last row of ToggleButtons. I'm not sure if this is an iteration problem, a problem with the grouping, or what.

Current code:

```
class RatingScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RatingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        global logsession, logdate, interfererlist
        #layouts
        ratingpage = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.row = GridLayout(cols=5)
        nav = GridLayout(cols=3, size_hint=(1,.15))

        #widgets
        currentlabel = Label(text=(f'You are logging interferers for {logsession} on {logdate}.'), size_hint=(1, .15))
        resetbtn = Button(text="Reset", on_press=self.resetbtn)
        backbutton = Button(text="back", on_press = self.backtoint)
        savebtn = Button(text='save', on_press = self.saveint)


        #add widgets to layout
        self.add_widget(ratingpage)
        ratingpage.add_widget(currentlabel)
        self.row.add_widget(Label(text='Interferer'))
        self.row.add_widget(Label(text='Intensity'))
        self.row.add_widget(Label(text="Contact Made"))
        self.row.add_widget(Label(text='Mitigation'))
        self.row.add_widget(Label(text='Aggro'))


        for index, row in interfererlist.iterrows():
            intname = Label(text=str(row['House Name']))
            self.intensityrating = GridLayout(cols=3)
            self.intcon = CheckBox()
            self.intmit = CheckBox()
            self.intagg = CheckBox()
            self.row.add_widget(intname)
            self.row.add_widget(self.intensityrating)
            for n in range(1,4):
                self.ratebtn = ToggleButton(text=f'{n}', group=str(row['Accession Number']))
                self.intensityrating.add_widget(self.ratebtn)
                self.ratebtn.rate = str({n})
                self.ratebtn.int = str({row['Accession Number']})


            self.row.add_widget(self.intcon)
            self.row.add_widget(self.intmit)
            self.row.add_widget(self.intagg)

        ratingpage.add_widget(self.row)
        ratingpage.add_widget(nav)
        nav.add_widget(backbutton)
        nav.add_widget(resetbtn)
        nav.add_widget(savebtn)


    def saveint(self, instance):
        pass

    def resetbtn(self, instance):
        for child in self.row.children:
            if isinstance(child, CheckBox):
                child.state = 'normal'

        for col in self.row.children:
            for child in self.intensityrating.children:
                if isinstance (child, ToggleButton):
                    child.state = 'normal'

    def backtoint(self, instance):
        self.manager.current= 'interfererscreen'

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.clear_widgets()
```

resetbtn is where I am having my issues. The first part, for checkmarks, works fine on all rows. I've tried a few things for the ToggleButton, shown is trying to figure out how to iterate through the GridLayout of the three togglebuttons.

Using this works for the previous screen, which is just a GridLayout of toggle buttons, no grouping.

```
    def resetbtn(self, instance):
        global interfererlist
        for child in self.potint.children:
            if isinstance (child, ToggleButton):
                child.state = 'normal'
                #reset list to empty when buttons are reset
                interfererlist = pd.DataFrame()
```

My other thought is to clear all widgets and run on_enter again, but I think I'm just going to run into this problem when I need to iterate through the rows to save the entered values (I haven't coded the save function yet).

I'm very new to Kivy, and to OOP in general, so I'm hoping there's something simple I'm overlooking. I've written this all without a .kv file in an effort to manipulate everything in python, but I know the .kv file might be inevitable.

---

ETA:
It seems I got it to work! I discovered widget.walk() and that seems to have done it. Hoping to use this going forward to 'save' my input.

```
        for child in self.row.walk():
            if isinstance (child, ToggleButton):
                child.state = 'normal'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is in your `on_enter()` method where you are redefining `self.intensityrating` in a loop. So when that loop completes, `self.intensityrating` contains the last value that you set in the loop, and that is what is used to set the `state` of those `ToggleButons` later in the `resetbtn()` method. You probably need to consider a different method of keeping track of the `ToggelButtons`.

Comment: Ah!! I think you're right, I had a feeling it had something to do with looping. If I don't create these widgets in on_enter, where should I have that loop?

Comment: The issue is not where that loop is, it is the loop itself and the redefining of `self.intensityrating`.